# Use induction to show that a series is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction, convex-analysis

I'm having trouble with this:

Use induction to show that $f(x) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^nr_i(x-x_i)^2$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}$ where $\{r_1, \dots, r_n\}$ are positive numbers and $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ are fixed points.

I really don't know where to start or go, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Prove that a sum of convex functions is convex.

Comment: @dxiv ah, so if I can show that the basis step is convex, then I should know that the sum of all the convex functions would therefore be convex? I guess I keep getting stuck on the argument of showing that $r_1(x-x_1)^2$ is convex.

Comment: You need to show that the base case is convex, indeed, then inductively that a sum of $n+1$ convex functions is convex. For the base case, a positive constant factor $r_1$ doesn't change convexity, so you can just focus on $(x-x_1)^2\,$, which can be proved to be convex either from the definition directly, or using the second derivative sign.

Answer (score 0):

Convexity of $r_1(x-x_1)^2\,$: Notice that the second derivative of this is $2r_1$ which is positive. Hence is strictly convex ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)).

Now induction hypothesis being: $n$ terms summation is convex. Need to prove $n+1$ terms summation is convex. Refer "[Prove that the sum of convex functions is again convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1370235/prove-that-the-sum-of-convex-functions-is-again-convex)" for the proof.